# Reason for @@TRANCOUNT check?

Tags: ola-hallengren

we're using the SQL functions from Ola Hallengren since many years. Sometime between 2015 and 2018 the check for open transactions was added in IndexOptimize. So now, after upgrade to the current version, the sp fails with "The transaction count is not 0."

Question: What's the functional reason for the check? It seems to me, that the old version w/o the check was running fine too. Is it safe to remove the check?

Regards
Holger

Comment: Why are you running the procedure in a transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are running `IndexOptimize` within an existing transaction.  Ola's script is checking for an open transaction close to the very start of the procedure.

Would you *really* want the `IndexOptimize` process running under **ONE** transaction and possibly filling up the log along with possible blocking.

Ola's code has a variety of `begin transaction` and `commit` statements.  If the process is already running under a transaction, additional `begin transaction` statements create nested transactions and the subsequent `commit` statements only decrement the `@@trancount`, but don't actually `commit` the work.

Try running the process without an explicit `begin transaction`.

Comment: Hi Tom, hi Scott,

Thank you for the fast reactions. I understand the technical reason for adding the check and for the message, but my problem is:

I can't control it. 

We run the script regularly, sometimes there is work and an open transaction, sometimes not. But we need reliability.

Comment: After reading you suggestions I've revised the code. The old version form year 2015 doesn't have a "BEGIN TRANSACTION". In the current version is one location, inside a block with "IF @DatabasesInParallel = 'Y'". This is if you specify more than one database and want to process them in parallel. But we've only one database at a time. So from my point of view the following should work:

We ensure the no one can use "@DatabasesInParallel = 'Y'" by forcing a "N".
We comment the transaction check.

I know, this is on my own risk. 

Any exceptions?

Regards
Holger

Comment: @Holger_HH - Any changes you make to Ola's script will certainly be lost on a subsequent download unless you take care to port changes you make to the downloaded version.  I'm not Ola, but I still believe the check toward the beginning of the procedure is there to keep the entire process from running under a single transaction.  An option is - before you run Ola's script, you could check for `@@Trancount >0` then `commit` and then leave Ola's script alone.

Comment: Yes, I know. We don't use the original scripts, we use a modified version, where we changed from db scheme to our own. And committing the open transacion is from my point of view a major risk. I don't know the transaction and the application.

Comment: @Holger_HH - well, since you are already modifying Ola's scripts AND since Ola's scripts appear to have `commit` statements to go with every `begin transaction` statement, I don't know why you can't just remove the check for `@@Trancount<>0` at the beginning of his procedure.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but this is what I've done now. Just removed the check. I understand your answer "An option is - before you run Ola's script, you could check for @@Trancount >0 then commit and then leave Ola's script alone." that I should add the transaction check and an commit before starting the sp to close the open transaction. Sorry.

Comment: @Holger_HH - yes, your latest comment accurately represents my intention.  I _think_ you should be fine by just removing the `@@Trancount<>0` check at the very beginning of Ola's procedure.

Comment: When I started using transactions in the stored procedures, I also introduced the @@TRANCOUNT check.

This is to avoid scenarios like that a user aborts the stored procedure execution, and then starts it again, with an open transaction.

Comment: @Holger_HH, could you describe a bit more how you are executing the stored procedure? Where does the transaction get started?